# Skip port compilation for certain OS?

Tags: compilation, erlang, rebar

I have a Rebar-based Erlang application that builds a port program.  This port program is Linux-specific, so compilation fails on Mac OS.  However, I'd like Rebar to just skip the port program when building on Mac OS.  How can I do that?

The current spec in `rebar.config` looks like this:

```
{port_specs, [{"priv/my_port", ["c_src/foo.c", "c_src/bar.c"]}]}.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [documented in comments in rebar_port_compiler.erl](https://github.com/basho/rebar/blob/f0bf3503cb470523db540a1f2080547450de3387/src/rebar_port_compiler.erl#L41), the list elements for `port_specs` have an alternative form `{ArchRegex, TargetFile, Sources}`.  So write your Rebar configuration like this:

```
{port_specs, [{"linux", "priv/my_port", ["c_src/foo.c", "c_src/bar.c"]}]}.
```

"What is that regex matched against?", you might ask.  It is matched against the return value of [rebar_utils:get_arch](https://github.com/basho/rebar/blob/f0bf3503cb470523db540a1f2080547450de3387/src/rebar_utils.erl#L75), which consists of the following parts, separated by hyphens:

- The OTP release as returned by `erlang:system_info(otp_release)`, e.g. `"R15B02"`
- The system architecture as returned by `erlang:system_info(system_architecture)`.  For Unix-like systems, this is the CPU-vendor-OS triplet determined by the configure script, e.g. `"i386-apple-darwin10.8.0"` or `"x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"`.
- The emulator word size, 32 or 64, based on the return value of `erlang:system_info({wordsize, external})`.
- The OS family, `unix` or `win32`.  (The first element of the tuple returned by `os:type/0`)

So the end result will be something like `"R15B01-i386-apple-darwin10.8.0-32-unix"` or `"R15B02-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-64-unix"`.